# Use a dataset to replace value in another dataset using Python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataset, data-analysis

I have a huge dataset 'A' for car's price prediction having certain columns. One of the columns is 'city', and I want to give rank to each city to use it for a ML algorithm. The cities are more than 50, so replacing at run-time doesn't make the code look good.

I want to make a .csv containing the 'city' and 'rank' and replace and use that 'rank' in dataset 'A'. How can I do that in python or pandas? Any example or code snippet would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scikit's labelEncoder, it will transform each unique name to a code.
DANGER: note that the codes are given at random and are nominal (not ordinal) meaning that the relative numbers of the cities don't have any meaning. 
In the example below, tokyo is 2, paris is 1. Is that because Tokyo has greater population? Or anything meaningful? NO. It is random, therefore, most of the time it is not suitable for being an ML feature.
The doc for Label enconder is [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

You can also look into the one-hot encoder that turns each value into a column of 1's and 0's. That is usually how you incorporate categoricals into ML.

For more info do google searches like "nominal vs ordinal categorical features", or "how to incorporate categoricals into scikit ml" etc...

```
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
LabelEncoder()
>>> list(le.classes_)
['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo']
>>> le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"]) 
array([2, 2, 1]...)
>>> list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris']
```

Comment: wow that was great information since I have just started this. But as I said my data set it very very large, like ~67k rows. I cannot write all the names in the code, I want to call the row from my data set and do Label encoding, s this possible?

Comment: This is just example from docs, you would need to change the fit statement to: le.fit(A['city']).  Then, A['codes']= le.transformA['city']). This gives you new column called codes